# Drag Formula over but keep Letter and change number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am looking at inserting a simple formula that captures prices for the month that is held on the site sheet vertically into a master sheet horizontally.

I want to enter a formula `='Site Name'!$E$6` (for October) and to then drag into November and for the formula to then be `='Site Name'!$E$7`, then `8`, `9`, `10` right up to March.

When I currently do this, the formula changes to `='Site Name'!$D$6`. Is there a way to do what I am after?

Site Sheet

[image]

Master Sheet

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX('Site Name'!$E:$E,COLUMN(A1)+5)
```

Now as it is dragged to the right it will change the row reference to +1.

Comment: I Have tried your formula but it does not seem to return any values, even though I know that there is a figure in there.
=INDEX(Brigton!$P:$P,COLUMN(P174)+5) and when I drag the forumla right the Cell changes to Q174. 
I would be looking for the cell to be (P175) going down the way.

Comment: Change `COLUMN(P174)+5` to `COLUMN(A1)+173`

Comment: The `COLUMN(A1)` is simply a counter that changes from `A1` to `B1` and the column number returned turns from `1` to `2` as it is dragged over.  Thus increasing the row number reference passed to the index as it is dragged over from `174` to `175`

Comment: Got it working, Thanks